# Open second window when laravel app opens

Tags: laravel

I am creating an app with Laravel that is supposed to use GoogleMaps API to show certain data in the map.

What I want to achieve is, that when you browse the root of the app, so when the user hits the main website, a new window is opened that will show a map to work with. So I want to have the ability to work with a second screen that only shows the map and all the information that should be displayed on the map.

How can I open a new window with certain content automatically when I browse to the main page.

Best
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern browsers prevent this from happening, as it's commonly abused to serve popup advertisements. You'll need to make the new window happen via a user action, like a click on a button.